# Game Theory - need references on analysis of particular game

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, game-theory

My hobby AI research have led me to a thorethical game of particular design. As design is pretty simple, I was sure that such game has well-known name. But my [question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710683/game-theory-trying-to-find-game-name-by-description), where I was trying to find any directions for future research, have died without acceptable answer. This makes me suspicious about accidentially stepping on new grounds, so I decided to try again here. <strike>Quoting myself</strike> Formulating game model more formally per @usul advice:

- Number of players: $N \ge 3$
- Simultaneous moves, each player have full information on previous rounds
- Number of rounds: variable with geometric distribution, not known to the players
- Possible moves: $R$ (bet on red), $B$ (bet on black), $R'$ (fold), $B'$ (fold)
- Round outcomes:

  $N_R$ - number of $R$ moves, $N_B$ - number of $B$ moves

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
              & R         & B         & R' & B' \\ \hline
  N_R \gt N_B & N_B / N_R & -1        & 0  & 0  \\
  N_R \lt N_B & -1        & N_R / N_B & 0  & 0  \\
  N_R = N_B   & 0         & 0         & 0  & 0
\end{array}

EDIT: Please, take note - I have simplified game description:

- only bets of value $1$ are allowed now
- two different folds have replaced "players can communicate between rounds" requirement

Does anyone know, if this or similar game have been researched already? If yes, any references are welcome. If no, any advices on how to crack this open are welcome too.

Comment: You might look up voting methods such as single transferable vote.  While  not quite the same, you may find some portions of the analysis applicable to your game, especially if a political party is considered a player.

Comment: Thank you for direction, @TheMaskedAvenger - reading papers on STV right now. From what I see already, my design definitely have some similarities with tactical voting situations - game rewards you for having supporters of your voting strategy, but punishes if your clique is _too_ big. Though, havent found a direct isomorphism yet. Too bad, most papers I see are about designing voting system to eleminate tactical voting, not about finding perfect tactical voting strategy :-)

Comment: You should try to make your model more formal and detailed. How many rounds are there? What does it mean to "communicate" between rounds? (Probably it doesn't matter for equilibrium analysis.) Do players keep the remainder that they choose not to bid?

Comment: @usul, thank you for advice - please, check fresh edit.

Comment: Why two fold strategies?

Comment: @Waldemar, two different folds are to be used as sort of public communication channel between players so they can naturally form cliques with shared strategies. They have no fixed semantics, but in some situation, for example, $X'$ can mean "my next move will not be $X$".

Comment: The only possible long-term strategies are the ones leading to zero expected payoff. E.g. everyone can always fold.

Comment: @Waldemar, and what if we tax folding with penalty of $-x$ where $0 < x \ll 1$?

Comment: Even if we exclude folding at all, it is still a case that only zero expected payoff strategies are possible. E.g. everyone can always choose $R$.